# update-grub is setting a wrong linux root partition

Tags: grub2, partitioning, root

Initially, Ubuntu was installed on another partition (sda5 or sda4).

At some point I did manually move the root partition to sda2.

Now, the problem is that whenever a new kernel is installed,  the automatic regeneration of the `menu.lst`  is using the OLD Linux partition. So I have to manually change in `menu.lst` the lines :

```
root            (hd0,5)
```

into

```
root            (hd0,1)
```

How can I configure `update-grub` to automatically generate `menu.lst` with the current Linux root partition? I assume that the (hd0,5)  was written somewhere at installation,  but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

Ever since grub2, `menu.lst` is not really used any more, so chances are you need to look elsewhere if you're having a problem with grub.

However, `menu.lst` is still sometimes used with the **Cloud version of Ubuntu**. If that applies to you, read on.

The auto-generated `root (hd0)` entries are actually configured by modifying the `/boot/grub/menu.lst` file. You need to find the lines that look like:

```
## default grub root device   
## e.g. groot=(hd0)
# groot=(hd0)
```

And change the last line to point to the new root, for example:

```
## default grub root device   
## e.g. groot=(hd0)
# groot=(hd0,5)
```

Notice that the `groot=…` line still begins with a `#`. **Do not uncomment the changed line!** I don't know what genius thought of having configuration parameters in commented out lines, but that's how it works.

Once you've made the change, regenerate `menu.lst` by running:

```
sudo update-grub-legacy-ec2
```

All the `root` entries in `menu.lst` should now be updated to point to `(hd0,5)` (or whatever you configured it to).

Answer (score 1):

One possibility that I have chosen is to tell grub to install at the master boot partition with

```
sudo fdisk -l                # where you get the disk
sudo grub-install /dev/hda   # in my computer it is /dev/sda
```

and then you update everything with:

```
update-grub2
```

Hope you succeed, you better wait for an expert answer.